# Querying second-level cache in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate

## The setup

### The mapping

I've got a MyItem class which has a lazy loaded collection consisting of MyDetail items:

```
[Serializable]
class MyItem : IComparable, ICloneable
{
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class MyDetail : ICloneable
{
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual MyItem EnclosingItem { get; set; }
}

void MyItemMap(IClassMapper<MyItem> ca)
{
  ca.Lazy(false);
  ca.Cache(cm => { cm.Usage(CacheUsage.NonstrictReadWrite); cm.Region(cacheRegion); });
  ca.Id(x => x.ID, cm => { cm.Generator(Generators.Native); });
  ca.Discriminator(cm => { cm.Column("Type"); cm.Type(NHibernateUtil.String); });
  ca.Bag(x => x.Details, cm =>
  {
    cm.Key(k => k.Column("ItemID"));
    cm.Inverse(true);
    cm.Type<DetailFactory>();
    cm.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
    cm.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Select);
    cm.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
    cm.Cache(m => { m.Usage(CacheUsage.NonstrictReadWrite); });
  } cr => cr.OneToMany());
}

void MyDetailMap(IClassMapper<MyDetail> ca)
{
  ca.Lazy(true);
  ca.Cache(cm => { cm.Usage(CacheUsage.NonstrictReadWrite); cm.Region(cacheRegion); });
  ca.Id(x => x.ID, cm => { cm.Generator(Generators.Native); });
  ca.ManyToOne(x => x.EnclosingItem, cm => { cm.Column("ItemID"); cm.NotNullable(true); cm.Fetch(FetchKind.Select); cm.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy); });
}
```

### The collection

The class to load the associated MyDetail items is a PersistentGenericBag:

```
class DetailList : PersistentGenericBag<MyDetail>
{
}
```

### The collection factory

This happens through a custom collection factory:

```
class DetailFactory : IUserCollectionType
{
  public IPersistentCollection Instantiate(ISessionImplementor session, ICollectionPersister persister)
  {
    return new DetailList(session);
  }

  public IPersistentCollection Wrap(ISessionImplementor session, object collection)
  {
    return new DetailList(session, (IList<MyDetail>)collection);
  }
}
```

## The problem

Suppose I've loaded a MyItem and I've requested Details at least once, so my second level cache (SLC) contains all these things. Also suppose I'm only actively using 1 Detail, while there are actually 100 details connected to MyItem. This means that whenever I access MyItem from the SLC and access the one detail I'm interested in, the whole collection is materialized:

```
// Get item coming from SLC
MyItem myItem = nhSession.Get(id);

// Access detail, materializing all MyDetails from SLC
MyDetail myDetail = myItem.Details["Interesting"];

// Normally, this last line will invoke the default NH proxy
// which then materializes the Details collections, fetching
// all details belonging to myItem from the database, or from
// the SLC for that matter.
//
// To cater for my scenario, I've got access to an interceptor
// to do my own processing (the details to how this is hooked
// up are not very relevant). This interceptor should somehow
// be able to, instead of initializing the collection, return
// the result from the SLC rightaway. This would prevent
// the materialization of possibly large collections.
```

## Solving the optimization problem

Now I'd like to optimize this scenario by bypassing the collection loading, and directly querying the SLC for presence of that detail. Note that my problem is not intercepting the actual detail call from the code, but intervening in what is returned in what way.

I'm using the SysCache, so theoretically I could read out the ASP.NET cache, but since the cache keys are an implementation detail of NH, I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Does anyone have a pointer for me?

Comment: Please can you provide the definitions for MyItem and MyDetails and the mappings for the MyDetails class?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to abstract the essence away from the codebase, but I edited the question

Comment: In the question you access a Detail by `myItem.Details["Interesting"]`. Is this a custom indexer?

Comment: I added some comments. In essence, yeah, your talking about a custom indexer. Fyi, I'm at this very moment setting up a unit test to work out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working, but the net effect is that my app is now even taking longer. As this doesn't make sense to me yet, I'm still investigating, but I'll post the code already anyway.

First I hooked up a listener. It inserts an extra mapping everytime a MyDetail is saved. That means that, besides having the ID's of MyDetail in the SLC, I can also look them up by EnclosingItem.ID and MyDetail.Name.

```
class PostLoadListener : IPostLoadEventListener
{
  public void OnPostLoad(PostLoadEvent @event)
  {
    // Only act when MyDetail is loaded
    var detail = @event.Entity as MyDetail;
    if (detail == null) return;

    ISessionImplementor session = @event.Session;
    var persister = @event.Persister;

    // Still tak into account caching settings (copied over these checks from NH)
    if (persister.HasCache == false || ((session.CacheMode & CacheMode.Put) != CacheMode.Put)) return;

    // Create the mapping by combining the collection ID and the detail
    // name, which together are being mapped to the actual detail ID
    var id = detail.EnclosingItem.ID + "#" + detail.Name;
    var cacheKey = new CacheKey(id, NHibernateUtil.String, PersistentContentDetailsList.IdMapRole, session.EntityMode, session.Factory);

    // Cache the mapping [detail.EnclosingItem.ID#detail.Name] => [detail.ID]
    persister.Cache.Put(cacheKey, detail.ID, session.Timestamp, null, null, true);
  }
}
```

Then, I made sure my DetailList does the aforementioned lookups when applicable:

```
class DetailList : PersistentGenericBag<MyDetail>
{
  public MyDetail this[string name]
  {
    get { MyDetail detail; TryGetValue(name, out detail); return detail; }
    set { /* */  }
  }

  private IList<ContentDetail> List { get { return this; }
  }

  /*
  * If the collection was already initialized, it doesn't make sense
  * to reach for the SLC, so skip it in that case. If it wasn't,
  * then try to fetch from the SLC. If the detail wasn't found there,
  * initialize the collection by triggering the enumerator and
  * subsequently find the detail by name.
  */
  public bool TryGetValue(string name, out MyDetail value)
  {
    return
      (value = WasInitialized
                 ? List.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name)
                 : (GetCachedDetail(name) ?? List.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name))
      ) != null;
  }

  /*
  * GetCachedDetail uses the collection identifier, combines it with
  * the detail name, and tries to find that mapping in the SLC.
  * If it exists, the ID is returned. So basically, you get to know
  * which MyDetail to fetch from the SLC when you know its EnclosingItem
  * and its name.
  */
  private ContentDetail GetCachedDetail(string name)
  {
    var mapId = Key + "#" + name;
    var persister = Session.Factory.GetEntityPersister(typeof(ContentDetail).FullName);
    var key = new CacheKey(mapId, NHibernateUtil.String, IdMapRole, Session.EntityMode, Session.Factory);
    var cacheEntry = persister.Cache.Get(key, Session.Timestamp);

    // This last step might be optimized by only executing the relevant 
    // loading statements of the Session.Load invocation chain
    return cacheEntry != null ? ((ISession)Session).Load<MyDetail>((int)cacheEntry) : null;
  }
}
```